# How to get the focus (cursor) from the editor to the panel(terminal) visual studio code extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, focus, vscode-extensions

I am writing a visual studio code extension and at some point, when I call a command to open and run a script at the terminal, I want simultaneously the terminal to take the focus (cursor) from everywhere else.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as this:

```js
vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.terminal.focus");
```

You're basically invoking a command with the same identifier you'd use if you were to assign it to a keyboard shortcut - and you can look up other commands in the editor itself if you invoke `workbench.action.openGlobalKeybindings`.

Documented [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#commands.executeCommand).

Comment: Do you maybe also know how I could open a new terminal in the vscode panel (if there is not an active one) but not a powershell but a bash terminal (like the git bash). Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm a VSCode newbie and I don't understand where to put the `vscode.commands...`. Will this solve my problem?: after I type `print(input("Enter:")) in the editor and click run configuration or F5, the focus will automatically jump to the terminal window without having to press ctrl+`.